# Can a computer behind a NAT-router receive realtime-updates from facebook?

Tags: facebook, networking, facebook-graph-api, webserver, nat

I'm currently writing a desktop application that integrates facebook using the graph API. I'd like to implement real-time updates (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime/), but in the doc it say's that you have to establish a http server that facebook will address to send the updates to. My problem is now that my box is sitting behind a router with only one IP-address (so the router uses NAT).
Will it still be possible for facebook to contact my webserver for sending me updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@kohlehydrat: Every webserver needs to have an IP address that can be reached from "anywhere" on the internet. Since your webserver is sitting behind a NAT with only one IP, I seriously doubt Facebook can reach your webserver.

However, see if you can configure the NAT in such a way to reserve a dedicated port for your application.

For example:

```
        10.122.48.222:4231 
traffic to port 4231 is directed towards your application. 
10.122.48.222 is outward facing NAT IP address.
```

I am not sure if we can do this, but its an idea.

Answer (score 1):

The router should catch port 80 requests (or whatever port your webserver is supposed to listen on) and forward it to your internal computer port 80, preferably in a consistent NAT style.

Basically, IP based communication with proper routing should not be an issue if both parties can find each other.

Comment: So I can simply create (with java) a webserver, and I won't have to worry whether facebook will be able to reach it? / It is handled completely transparent?

Comment: @kohlehydrat:  If your router has a static IP address, yes.  If your router has a dynamic IP address, because your Internet service provider uses a group of IP adresses, then no.

Answer (score 1):

You Need to Do what is called as **"PORT FORWARDING"**.
I had a similar issue initially, Then I **forwarded my port** where in my IP was Made **Public** from being **local** only to the company.
And now my issue is solved.
hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this question is already closed, but since you have not received this particular answer (which is what I believe most facebook developers do in order to develop behind firewalls) I will post it here:

You can reverse tunnel your machine to any machine with a publically available ip.
see [blog post on this topic](http://blog.kenweiner.com/2007/09/reverse-ssh-tunnel-for-facebook.html)

in a lot of facebook sdks, this functionality is even included ( for instance, facebooker, a ruby gem provides the functionality to rake facebooker:tunnel:start after you setup the appropriate settings)